# gulp errors: "LiveReload disabled because it could not find its own <SCRIPT> tag"

Tags: javascript, html, web, gulp

I have a simple web exercise with an `index.html` and a `script.js` file. I have gulp running in the background for real-time preview in the browser. This is how my `HTML` looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Empty Page</title>
    <!-- <script src="script.js" defer></script> -->
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

So this works so far, but the moment I re-introduce the `script.js` bit, the live browser preview stops working and I see the following error in the console:

`LiveReload disabled because it could not find its own <SCRIPT> tag`

These are the contents of the `script.js` file:

```
var date = Date();
document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>Today is? " + date + "</h1>"
```

And this here is my `gulpfile.js` file:

```
// Include Gulp
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Include required plugins.
var connect = require('gulp-connect');

// TASK: connect
gulp.task('connect', function() {
  connect.server({
      livereload: true
  });
});

// TASK: preview
gulp.task('preview', function () {
    gulp.src('index.html')
        .pipe(connect.reload());
});

// TASK: watch
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('*.html', ['preview']);
    gulp.watch('*.js', ['preview']);
});

gulp.task('run', function() {
    console.log('warnning: No project [run] parameters configured.');
});

// Task Bundles
gulp.task('default', ['connect', 'watch']);
```

Comment: After some further investigation, I solved the issue by adding this to my index.html file's `<script>` tag: `<script src="http://localhost:35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" async="" defer=""></script>` Not very elegant, but fixed the error :(

Comment: It is hard to believe that no one has come across this problem? :(

Comment: I have started an isuse here, but with not much of a response. https://github.com/AveVlad/gulp-connect/issues/254